# Thread safe spinning with Mutex and boost::threads

Tags: ros, boost, thread, spinning

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have several threads accessing the same function. To guarantee safe spinning, which means none of the threads calls        `ros::spinOnce()` at the same time I used a regular mutex. So if the threads wants to spin he has to lock it before, so in case he gets interrupted another thread cannot spin meanwhile, until the locking thread gets cpu-time again and releases the lock.
 Is this approach good/bad Idea?

```
    boost::mutex safespinmutex;
    #include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
    #include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
    #include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
    boost::mutex mtx_spin;           //shared by publisher threads

    //thread safe regular mutex spin
    mtx_spin.lock();
    ros::spinOnce();
    mtx_spin.unlock();
    loop_rate.sleep();
}
```

It is similar to c11 mutex, just here I use c98 syntax with `boost::threads and boost::mutex` :)
**Edit more Info**
 I spawn a maximum of 13 threads each dedicated to publishing, which is a lot, but I dont see any problem: The call to `lock()` blocks the thread if another thread is inside the `spinOnce()` but yet not finished. Once done this thread unlocks the mutex and unblocks the waiting thread. voila or am I conceptually wrong?
This is how I start the publishing threads

```
      boost::thread tpool[14]; //thread pool
      int pool = 0;

  for (unsigned i=0; i<13; i++){
        if(rate_eff[i]!=0) {
            tpool[pool++] = boost::thread(publisher,(i+1), use_def);
        }
    }
    cout<<"        publishing on "<<(pool-1)<<" topics:"<<endl;
```

**Benchmark**
To confirm what said above I spawned 9 topics each managed by their own publisher thread. One Incoming thread sorts stuff into the internal vectors rate(100Hz) and the 9 publisher threads read it with `1000Hz rate` and push it onto their topic. Does it run safe: Yes. 
 I am glad about suggestions and improvements but please fortify your statement. 
 [image: image description]

In case you want to have a look at the complete code [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_MzoTKF7WAidTRheVFvT3Q4YlE/view?usp=sharing).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226579/thread-safe-spinning-with-mutex-and-boost::threads/) by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on ROS Answers with karma: 748 on 2016-02-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Spinning from multiple threads seems like a complex solution to a simple problem. Why not just have a separate thread dedicated to spinning?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on 2016-02-15**:
I do have seperate threads dedicated to spinning, BUT if two threads call `spinOnce()` at the same time needs to be avoided at all time. That's why each thread who wants to spin first accquires a mutx shared by all threads, so he knows he's the only one and allowed to do so. Am I conceptually wrong?

**Comment by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on 2016-02-15**:
If you mean with `a separate thread` just one thread, is what I try to avoid as it might be too much to process before spinning

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-02-15**:
Each publish thread does not need to call spinOnce(). I would create a thread which does nothing but call `ros::spin()` and which does not do any other processing. ROS publishers are thread-safe, so there are no issues with calling `publish()` in one thread and spinning in another thread.

**Comment by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on 2016-02-15**:
I wish I knew this before that publish and spin could be seperated.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-02-16**:
The [C++ Publisher Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29#roscpp_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingPublisherSubscriber.The_Code_Explained) is pretty clear about `ros::spinOnce()` being unrelated to publish, and only required for callbacks.